# Not able to receive broadcast in other app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I was learning broadcast receiver concept, so I tried making demo apps for sending broadcast and receiving custom private broadcast

This is my Broadcast Sender App code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView senderTextView;
Button sendButton;
private int counter;

//This is our anonymous class which will receive broadcast when sent from send button and set our text view
private final BroadcastReceiver innerReceiverAnonymousClass = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //if our (com.example.PRIVATE_BROADCAST) broadcast equals to the intent received here from intent filter
        if("com.example.PRIVATE_BROADCAST".equals(intent.getAction())){
            //counter variable for tracking no. of times broadcast is sent
            counter++;
            //then this means broadcast has been sent in mobile
            //set text
            senderTextView.setText("Broadcast Sent " + counter + " times");
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initializing views
    senderTextView = findViewById(R.id.senderTextView);
    sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    //Setting onClick Listener on sendButton
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Calling Broadcast Method
            Broadcast();
        }
    });


}
//Broadcast Method
private void Broadcast(){
    //Creating private broadcast event
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.PRIVATE_BROADCAST");
    //Adding String to our intent
    intent.putExtra("BROADCAST_EXTRA_DATA","This is Private Broadcast");
    //Sending our private broadcast to our android mobile
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Intent filter will filter out intent from all the broadcasts happening in mobile
    // on basis of action and pass it to innerReceiverAnonymousClass
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.PRIVATE_BROADCAST");
    registerReceiver(innerReceiverAnonymousClass,intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(innerReceiverAnonymousClass);
}
```

This is my Broadcast Receiver app :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView receiverTextView;

//Our anonymous private broadcast receiver class
//We can also make a separate class java class that will extend BroadcastReceiver class
//But we are using an anonymous so that we can get control of text view i.e. UI
private final BroadcastReceiver privateBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if("com.example.PRIVATE_BROADCAST".equals(intent.getAction())){
            Log.d("APP_LOGS", "Broadcast Received");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Private Broadcast Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String broadcastString = intent.getStringExtra("BROADCAST_EXTRA_DATA");
            receiverTextView.setText("Broadcast Received : " + broadcastString);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    receiverTextView = findViewById(R.id.receiverTextView);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.PRIVATE_BROADCAST");
    registerReceiver(privateBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(privateBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

When I press send Broadcast button textview inside sender activity sets to "Broadcast sent 1 times which means our intent is getting broadcasted but toast from my receiver app doesn't show which means I am not able to get broadcast there.
Can someone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your receiver app will only receive the broadcast while that activity is in the foreground. Your sender app sends the broadcast when you click the button, which implies that its own activity is in the foreground. On most phones, only one of those things will be in the foreground at once. So, if you click the button, the receiver app is not in the foreground, and so it will not receive the broadcast.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh yes i need to register it in onCreate and unregister it in onDestroy ... Slipped my mind thanks.

Comment: Yes, that should work better for your experiment.